# Generating Function from using sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am new to generating function and having a hard time figuring out generating function using sequence. The question that I am having trouble on is using the sequence a<sub>r</sub> = $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{i} {r} $, find the generating function. There is a hint using $\sum_{r>=0}{}$ a<sub>r</sub> $x^r $. I the r in ar is lower  Can you please help. Thank you.

Comment: "There is a hint using" ... ?

Comment: Is the sequence $a_r$? Is it $a_r = \sum_{i = 0}^r {r \choose i}$?

Comment: @DavidW yes, my bad

Comment: What is $n$ here? Did you want to type $ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{r}$ instead?

Comment: The question says its n so i cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function for the sequence $\langle a_r:r\ge 0\rangle$ is by definition

$$g(x)=\sum_{r\ge 0}a_rx^r\,;$$

since $a_r=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}r$, we can write this as

$$g(x)=\sum_{r\ge 0}\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}rx^r\,.$$

$\binom{i}r=0$ when $i<r$, so every term of $a_r=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}r$ is $0$ when $r>n$. This means that $a_r=0$ when $r>n$, so

$$g(x)=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}rx^r\,:$$

it’s actually a polynomial of degree $n$.

$$\begin{align*}
g(x)&=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}rx^r\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{i}rx^r\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{r=0}^i\binom{i}rx^r\cdot 1^{i-r}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n(x+1)^i\,.
\end{align*}$$

This is a finite geometric series, so you should be able to express it in closed form; it’s not hard to simplify that closed form to a polynomial.

That approach works even if you know only the most basic facts about binomial coefficients. If you know the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), you can rewrite $g(x)$ as

$$\sum_{i=0}^nx^r\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{i}r$$

and apply the hockey stick identity to get the polynomial directly.

Comment: I will continue the step and can you correct me if i am wrong. $\sum_{i=0}^{n} (x+1)^i =  1 + (x+1)^1 + ... + (x+1)^n = S $. Then I get $(x+1)S = (x+1)^1 + (x+1)^2 + ... + (x+1)^n * (x+1)$. Subtract  S from (x+1)S --> $S - (x+1)S = 1 - (x+1)^n * (x+1)$ --> $xS = 1 - (x+1)^n * (x+1) $. Therefore, the close form of g(x) is $S =  \frac{1 - (x+1)^n * (x+1)}{x}$.

Comment: @TaAnhMinh: Almost, but you have a sign error: it’s $$\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1}x\,.$$ And after you expand $(x+1)^{n+1}$ using the binomial theorem and subtract $1$, there will be a factor of $x$ to cancel, leaving a polynomial.

Comment: oh yes, i forgot about the sign. So S - (x+1) S = -xS = $ 1-(x+1)^{n+1}$. Then S = $\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1} {x}$. Thank you very much

Comment: May i ask how to extract coefficient $x^n$ from this closed form?

Comment: @TaAnhMinh: By the binomial theorem $$(x+1)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}kx^k\,;$$ the constant term is $\binom{n+1}0=1$, so subtracting $1$ leaves $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^k$, and dividing by $x$ and shifting the index leaves $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k+1}x^k$.

Comment: sorry, i am trying to get head around it. I will try to take this step by step. Based on your answer, first step here is I do is separate $\frac {(x+1)^{n+1} -1} {x} $ into $((x+1)^{n+1} -1) * \frac{1}{x}$. Then convert $(x+1)^{n+1}$ into $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} * x^k$ and 1 into $\binom {n+1}{0}$. Perform subtraction: $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} * x^k - \binom {n+1}{0} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x^k$. Then divide the answer to x and get the final answer as $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{k+1} x^k$. Is this the steps? Thank you

Comment: @TaAnhMinh: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: The question says: "$a_r$ can be written as one binomial coefficient, which depends on r and n. What is this binomial coefficient?" Based on your hint, I tried to finish the question. So I used what you have given me with and now I have $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{r+1} x^r$. $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{r+1} x^r = g(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{i}{r} x^r$. We can see that $\binom{n+1}{r+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{i}{r}$. Therefore, the binomial coefficient is: $\binom {n+1}{r+1}$. Can you check my answer?

Comment: @TaAnhMinh: That’s correct.